# Align points with background png in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, png

I am trying to crease a grid of points corresponding to luminescence values in a 384-well plate experiment. I am drawing the plate as a .png file and overlaying the grid such that each point should sit in one well of the plate. Example code and data provided.

Is it possible to do this with ggplot2?

I am using the following code (example data provided):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(png)
library(RCurl)
library(grid)

example.gg <- read.csv("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRcX5aMZGCp9Bs3BRZSg8k4o-kbSjOO5z3LsRxgIv4qJHz1fG-Argruje32OuZ2Tt2qPaNGksGr4Jia/pub?output=csv",
            row.names = 1)
example.gg$Row <- factor(example.gg$Row, levels = rev(sort(unique(example.gg$Row))))

png.img <- readPNG(getURLContent("https://i.imgur.com/QeSO7d3.png"))
img.rg <- rasterGrob(png.img, interpolate=TRUE)

gp <- ggplot(example.gg,
             aes(x = Col, y = Row, col = Lum)) +
  annotation_custom(img.rg, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf) +
  geom_point(shape = 15) + 
  theme_void()
gp
```

And this is the image that gets made:

[image]

## Answer

Thanks to [Dan Adams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71115381/5436328) for original answer.

```
gp <- ggplot(example.gg,
             aes(x = Col, y = Row, col = Lum)) +
  annotation_custom(img.rg, 
                    xmin = -2,
                    xmax = 27,
                    ymin = -1,
                    ymax = 18) +
  geom_point(shape = 15, size = 2.5) + 
  theme_void()
gp + coord_fixed(clip = "off") +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(3, 6, 5, 2), "lines"),
        legend.position = c(1.2, 0.5)) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = pals::ocean.haline(100))
```

[image]

Comment: I would be _very_ tempted to do this entirely within ggplot.

Comment: My main issue is I don't know how to properly format the margins for the geom_points() object to control where the shapes land.

Comment: One thing that will probably help is setting the X:Y pitch to be 1 by using `coord_fixed()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By manually adjusting the position of the image with `xmin`/`xmax` & `ymin`/`ymax`, fixing the pitch of rows and columns with `coord_fixed(clip = "off)` and expanding the `plot.margin` in `theme` I was able to get something that seems like it will work.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(png)
library(RCurl)
library(grid)

example.gg <- read.csv("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRcX5aMZGCp9Bs3BRZSg8k4o-kbSjOO5z3LsRxgIv4qJHz1fG-Argruje32OuZ2Tt2qPaNGksGr4Jia/pub?output=csv",
            row.names = 1)
example.gg$Row <- factor(example.gg$Row, levels = sort(unique(example.gg$Row)))

png.img <- readPNG(getURLContent("https://i.imgur.com/QeSO7d3.png"))
img.rg <- rasterGrob(png.img, interpolate=TRUE)

gp <- ggplot(example.gg,
       aes(x = Col, y = Row, col = Lum)) +
  annotation_custom(
    img.rg,
    xmin = -2,
    xmax = 27,
    ymin = -1,
    ymax = 18
  ) +
  geom_point(shape = 15) +
  coord_fixed(clip = "off") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(3, 2, 5, 2), "lines"))
  
gp
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this. It works a treat! I've updated the original comment to reflect the answer and provided an example of the final plot.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that! As a wet biologists I am looking at plate data all the time so I completely understand the need here. If @Allan Cameron comes up with a nice drawing of a 384-well plate in ggplot I would love to see it because it will be less of a hack each time to get it adjusted to fit the plot.

Comment: Yep it would be very cool if this entire thing could be made as a single self-contained call to ggplot2

Comment: I thought I better put my money where my mouth is. See my answer below, though I don't think it's any improvement on the existing answers, it's nice to see what can be done within ggplot.

Answer (score 4):

I love a challenge, so here's the whole thing as a single ggplot call, without relying on any png files

```r
ggplot(example.gg, aes(factor(Col, levels = 1:24), Row, fill = Lum)) + 
  geom_tile(size = 6, color = "white") + 
  geom_label(label = "  ", fill = NA, label.padding = unit(0.3, "lines")) +
  annotation_custom(roundrectGrob(gp = gpar(fill = NA)), xmin = -2, 
                    xmax = 26, ymin = -1, ymax = 19) +
  annotation_custom(roundrectGrob(gp = gpar(fill = NA), r = unit(0.01, "npc")), 
                    xmin = 0.5, xmax = 24.5, ymin = 0.5, ymax = 16.5) +
  annotation_custom(polygonGrob(
    x = c(0.05, 0.99, 1, 1, 0.99, 0.05, 0, 0, 0.05), 
    y = c(0, 0, 0.01, 0.99, 1, 1, 0.9, 0.1, 0), gp = gpar(fill = NA)),
    xmin = -1.5, xmax = 25, ymin = 0, ymax = 18) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = pals::ocean.haline(100)) +
  theme_void() + 
  coord_equal(clip = "off") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.03, 0)) +
  guides(x = guide_axis(position = "top")) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.text.x.top = element_text(size = 12),
        plot.margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 40),
        legend.box.margin =  margin(20, 20, 20, 40))
```

[image]

Comment: Bravo, this is very impressive! I will plan use this (with attribution) in future! Just noticed that the y axis is reversed from what OP showed.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot I reversed the factor levels of the y variable before plotting.

Comment: Upon re-inspection I think yours is correct though. Not sure why OP wanted to flip it so the labels in the png are not matched to the raw data.

Comment: Definitely a mistake on my part for forgetting to fix the factor levels - have now amended in the question code.